# Why can't I deliver babies? - Fallout Shelter for iPhone

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have successfully mated all the women in my vault (last night around 1 am) and it is now 2 pm next day and I still have a vault full of pregnant ladies! What gives? Anyone else experiencing this issue? I know the game's new and likely to have bugs so I thought I'd ask before reporting the issue.

Comment: So many people are experiencing this you would think at least one person who posted a new question on it would notice the other 10 :D

Comment: Apparently this is a glitch that happens if you have demolished or upgraded the Living Quarters that the baby was conceived in. Since the new dweller spawns in the place where it was conceived, the AI doesn't know where to put it, so the woman just stays pregnant. I hope this helps. Bethesda knows about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have enough space in your vault for more dwellers, the deliveries will never occur. Build more living quarters. Chances are they will deliver right away after built and powered.